# Consequence async with Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following block code.

```js
if (response.messageCode === MESSAGE_CODE.SUCCESSS_AND_GENERATE_PDF) {
                                    // Open review pdf
                                    debugger;
                                    this.isOpenReviewPDF = true;
                                    setTimeout(() => {
                                        if (this.orderReviewPdfComponent.isViewInit) {
                                            setTimeout(() => {
                                                this.exportOrderReviewPDFAsync(this.orderEntry.customerOrderRequest.customerOrderId)
                                                    .then(() => {
                                                        this.successDialog(Message.TITLE_SAVE_BALANCE_SHEET_SUCCESSFULLY, Message.BODY_SAVE_BALANCE_SHEET_SUCCESSFULLY(this.orderEntry.customerOrderRequest.customerOrderId));
                                                        setTimeout(() => {
                                                            this.loading = false;
                                                        }, 300);
                                                    })
                                                    .catch(() => {
                                                        this.errorDialog(Message.TITLE_EXPORT_PDF_ORDER_ENTRY_FAILURE, Message.BODY_EXPORT_PDF_ORDER_ENTRY_FAILURE(this.orderEntry.customerOrderRequest.customerOrderId));
                                                        setTimeout(() => {
                                                            this.loading = false;
                                                        }, 300);
                                                    });
                                            });
                                        } else {
                                            this.successDialog(Message.TITLE_SAVE_BALANCE_SHEET_SUCCESSFULLY, Message.BODY_SAVE_BALANCE_SHEET_SUCCESSFULLY(this.orderEntry.customerOrderRequest.customerOrderId));
                                            this.loading = false;
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
```

How to make this code more clearly with Consequence async? I just updated my code

Comment: Can you clarify that final sentence? Also, those setTimeouts look dangerous. 

Comment: could you explain more about the danger?

Comment: I'm saying that on a hunch, and as a blind hint to you that it's probably not best practice to have all those setTimeouts in code that is already asynchronous. I'd be happy to offer more assistance, but you'll have to be more clear on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I don't think I'm understanding your question after reading the other responses and comments. It would help to see how you're calling this code. Can you provide more context?

Comment: @DanFletcher I just update my code. Here is my explain about my code. I have the function when I edit order --> save order -> generate pdf. Call API and the api will return message to generate pdf --> call this.isOpenReviewPDF  = true to open pdf component -> I wait for the component init and call the export pdf function. this.orderReviewPdfComponent.isViewInit === true when ngAfterViewInit() of pdfComponent. How can I wait it without setTimeout?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `Observable`. There are many advantages to use it.

1) Easy to use.

2) You can `subscribe` the response.

3) You are able to **cancel** the response.

4) It is in your hand to move your flow in next. As you can see in my answer I have used **next()** and **complete()**. When you call this then and then your code will move on next.

So when you want to work with **sync** flow. This is the most suitable option.

5) you can **delay** the process. without use of `setTimeout()...`.

6) You can create **your own Observable** and also you should `subscribe()` and `unsubscribe()` manually ... :)

**Try this way**

```
if (this.orderReviewPdfComponent.isViewInit) {
    return new Observable<any>(observer => {
        this.exportOrderReviewPDFAsync(this.customerOrderId)
            .then(() => {
                this.successDialog('success');
                    this.loading = false;
                    observer.delay(3000);
                    observer.next();
                    observer.complete();
            })
            .catch(() => {
                this.errorDialog('error');
                    this.loading = false;
                    observer.delay(3000);
                    observer.next();
                    observer.complete();
            });     
      })                    
} else {
    this.successDialog('success');
    this.loading = false;
    observer.next();
    observer.complete();
}
```

Comment: Don't you guys have delay operator? Why the set timeout in the first place?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Yes I we have , I have update my answer. :)

Comment: Is delay a function of observer? I'd think it's a function of Observable. I don't really know, I only know RxJava, I was just curious about this question :D

Answer (score 0):

Totally Agree with @Dan Comments, As Angular will trigger Change Detection for Async code using Zone.js, setTimeout block of code is not needed.

```
if (this.exportOrderReviewPDFAsync(this.customerOrderId) {
    return async () => {
        try {
            await this.exportOrderReviewPDFAsync(this.customerOrderId);
            this.successDialog('success');
            this.loading = false;
        } catch (error) {
            this.errorDialog('error');
            this.loading = false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: HI Suresh Kumar Ariya,


How about the first time out on my code? 
I wanna this code already is done before export pdf?

Comment: Yeah, that's fair. I guess I was assuming the OP wanted a delay for some reason.

Comment: Ok. Might be it depends on their requirement.